Recursive one-step forecasting in timeseries model
I am trying to implement a recursive one-step forecasting approach for a Random Forest model.
The idea is to get a 12-months forecast in an iterative way where each prediction becomes part of the history before the next prediction.
Given that I do not retrain the model and that the error of the model compounds on each recursive prediction step, I would expect the plot of error to be increasing steadily. However, there is no such trend.
I am wondering if there is any issue in the implementation. I want to test the predictive power of the model in a real-world scenario where we iteratively predict next values (e.g. if I want to have a 12 months forecast).
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(1)

# Create date range
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2024-12-31', freq='MS')
n_points = len(date_rng)

# Trend component (linear growth)
trend = np.linspace(100, 200, n_points)
seasonal = 20 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(n_points) / 12)
cyclical = 30 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(n_points) / (12 * 3))
noise = np.random.normal(0, 10, n_points)
values = trend + seasonal + cyclical + noise

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': date_rng,
    'value': values
})

# Format the data
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df['value'] = df['value'].round(2)


# build temporal features
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df['quarter'] = df.index.quarter
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['year'] = df.index.year
df['sin_month'] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * df.index.month / 12)
df['cos_month'] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * df.index.month / 12)

# Build lags
num_lags = 12
lagged_columns = {f'lag_{lag}': df['value'].shift(lag) for lag in range(1, num_lags + 1)}
df = df.assign(**lagged_columns)
df.dropna(inplace=True)

# Simple Moving Average (SMA)
sma_window_size = 12
df[f'SMA_{sma_window_size}'] = df['value'].rolling(window=sma_window_size).mean()

# Exponential Moving Average (EMA)
ema_span_size = 9
df[f'EMA_{ema_span_size}'] = df['value'].ewm(span=ema_span_size).mean()


# split data and fit model
split_point = '2023-12-31'

# Split into train and test
train = df.query('date <= @split_point')
test = df.query('date > @split_point')

# Create train features and target
X_train = train.drop(columns=['value', 'date'])
y_train = train['value']

# Create test features and target
X_test = test.drop(columns=['value', 'date'])
y_test = test['value']

rf_model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, 
                               max_depth=10,
                               random_state=0)
rf_model.fit(X_train, y_train)


# Number of forecast steps
num_forecasts = 12 
all_forecasts = {}

# get last train sample
X_last = train.iloc[[-1]].drop(columns=[col for col in train.columns.tolist() if col not in X_train.columns.tolist()])  # Drop identifiers that do not exist in X_train


forecasts = []

for step in range(num_forecasts):

    # Make prediction
    y_pred = rf_model.predict(X_last.values.reshape(1, -1))[0]
    forecasts.append(y_pred)

    # Update lags
    X_last_series = pd.Series(X_last.iloc[0])
    lags = X_last_series.filter(like='lag_').copy().shift(1, axis=0)
    lags['lag_1'] = y_pred
    X_last_series.update(lags)


    # Update seasonal or static features if necessary
    if 'month' in X_last_series.index and 'quarter' in X_last_series.index:
        # Month and Quarter
        current_month = X_last_series['month'] % 12 + 1

        X_last_series['month'] = current_month
        X_last_series['quarter'] = (current_month - 1) // 3 + 1
        
        # Year (increment if month wraps around to January)
        if current_month == 1:
            X_last_series['year'] += 1
            
        # Sinusoidal transformations for cyclical features (month)
        X_last_series['sin_month'] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * current_month / 12)
        X_last_series['cos_month'] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * current_month / 12)
    
    # Update rolling features
    if f'SMA_{sma_window_size}' in X_last_series.index:
        past_values = X_last_series.filter(like='lag_').values[:sma_window_size - 1]
        X_last_series[f'SMA_{sma_window_size}'] = np.mean(np.append(past_values, y_pred))

    if f'EMA_{ema_span_size}' in X_last_series.index:
        ema_alpha = 2 / (ema_span_size + 1)
        X_last_series[f'EMA_{ema_span_size}'] = ema_alpha * y_pred + (1 - ema_alpha) * X_last_series[f'EMA_{ema_span_size}']


    # Update X_last for the next forecast step
    X_last = X_last_series.to_frame().T

all_forecasts['results'] = {
'forecasts': forecasts,
'actuals': y_test
}


def calculate_mape(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100

steps_mape = []
for i in range(num_forecasts):  
    steps_mape.append(calculate_mape(y_test[i], forecasts[i]))

plt.plot(steps_mape)


EDIT: I though to look at the error from another point of view. Instead of calculating MAPE at each step, I now estimate cumulative MAPE over steps (e.g., MAPE at step 3 is the MAPE of the first three forecasts)
Like a running average up to each step.
Now things look more like expected however, I am wondering whether this approach is sound.
all_cumulative_mapes = []

# Loop over time series
for series_id, forecast_data in all_forecasts.items():
    actuals = forecast_data['actuals']
    forecasts = forecast_data['forecasts']

    cumulative_mape = []
    cumulative_error_sum = 0

    # Calculate cumulative MAPE over forecast steps
    for i in range(num_forecasts):
        # Calculate APE for current step
        ape = np.abs((actuals[i] - forecasts[i]) / actuals[i]) * 100
        
        # Update cumulative error sum and cumulative MAPE
        cumulative_error_sum += ape
        cumulative_mape_value = cumulative_error_sum / (i + 1)
        cumulative_mape.append(cumulative_mape_value)
    
    all_cumulative_mapes.append(cumulative_mape)

all_cumulative_mapes = np.array(all_cumulative_mapes)

plt.plot(np.mean(all_cumulative_mapes, axis=0), '-o', label="Average Cumulative MAPE")
plt.title(f"Average (across timeseries) Cumulative MAPE% over Forecast Steps")
plt.xlabel("Forecast Step")
plt.ylabel("Cumulative MAPE (%)")



Your noise is iid conditional on your temporal features. Why do you believe that "the error of the model compounds on each recursive prediction step"?

Good point, this is not maybe an excellent toy example but in reality I have timeseries from traffic that is similar to stock price timeseries in terms of patterns. If the code implementation is correct, then indeed it might just be a bad choice of input data in this case.

I edited my post adding another point of view. Open for discussion and feedback!
